# some echo statements doesnot work in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am working on a project and came across a problem where sometime echo function doesn't display anything or some parts of batch script has no action.

Here, `%Project_ModelSW_Path%` and all other path are defined in some other parts of the script.

The variable Build_type is not displayed in output and leaves blank.

at the line `echo %Build_type%` output is "echo is off".

Can anyone please help me why sometimes echo function doesn't display anything.

```
set COMMITTIME=%date:~-4%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-10,2%-%time:~-11,2%-%time:~-8,2%-%time:~-5,2%
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set COMMITTIME=!COMMITTIME:^ =0!
    setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
    echo ##%COMMITTIME%##


set Build_Type=Nightly_Build
if %time:~-11,2% GTR 5 set Build_Type=Normal_Build
echo %Build_Type%

svn commit %Project_ModelSW_Path%        -m "%Build_Type% %COMMITTIME%" || echo ERROR commiting ec_baic && exit /b
svn commit %Project_ModelSW_ALL_Path%        -m "%Build_Type% %COMMITTIME%" || echo ERROR commiting ec_baic && exit /b
    svn commit %Project_ModelSW_MDL_Path%        -m "%Build_Type% %COMMITTIME%" || echo ERROR commiting ec_baic && exit /b
```

I expect `Build_type` to display either `Nightly_Build` or `Normal_Build`.

Comment: I recommend using an `if else` statement for setting your build type variable. otherwise - it's likely your use of `setlocal` - instead of changing the expansion type, you should just `endlocal`. try changing `%Build_Type%` to `!Build_Type!` and see if it still gives you issues; i'm unable to reproduce the problem with the code you gave - unless Renat's formatting fixed it.

Comment: Thank you @mael  i added endlocal and replaced %Build_type% with !Build_Type!.. This solved my problem.

Comment: it's not problem - I went ahead and threw it in an answer so you could mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely due to how `setlocal` is being used; I recommend changing `setlocal disabledelayedexpansion` to `endlocal` and putting the `Build_Type` variable between exclamation marks:

```
set COMMITTIME=%date:~-4%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-10,2%-%time:~-11,2%-%time:~-8,2%-%time:~-5,2%
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set COMMITTIME=!COMMITTIME:^ =0!
    endlocal
    echo ##%COMMITTIME%##

if %time:~-11,2% GTR 5 (
    set "Build_Type=Normal_Build"
    ) else (
    set "Build_Type=Nightly_Build"
)

echo !Build_Type!
```

I also changed the `Build_Type` variable section to an `if then` statement.

Reference: [IF](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html), [setlocal](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)